# ReactJS handleHover change className

Tags: reactjs

I have Action componen

```
state = {
        highlight: null
    }
      handleLeave = () => {
        this.setState({
          highlight: null
      })
      }
      handleHover = (e) =>{
        this.setState({
          highlight: 'highlight'
      })
      }


    <img onMouseEnter={this.handleHover} onMouseLeave={this.handleLeave} className={`${this.state.highlight}`} src="img" />
```

but when I have a few images, like:

```
<img onMouseEnter={this.handleHover} onMouseLeave={this.handleLeave} className={`${this.state.highlight}`} src="img" />
 <img onMouseEnter={this.handleHover} onMouseLeave={this.handleLeave} className={`${this.state.highlight}`} src="img" />
```

then when you hover over one of them, everyone is given className 'highlight', 
but I want to highlight only image, on which i hover my mouse.
Thanks for answers in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can just use simple CSS to achieve a hover effect on your Images.

just like this:

```
img.anyClassName:hover {
    //css stuff
}
```

Shouldnt that be enough for your usage ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a higher order component approach.

```
// HOC that holds state/handlers and passes to wrapped component
    const handleHover = (Component) => 
      class extends React.Component {
        state = {
          highlight: null
        }

        handleLeave = () =>
          this.setState({
            highlight: null
          })

        handleHover = (e) =>
          this.setState({
            highlight: 'highlight'
          })

        render() {
          return (
            <Component
              handleHover={handleHover}
              handleLeave={handleLeave}
              highlight={this.state.highlight}
            />
          );
        }
      }

// Component that is wrapped with HOC that renders an <img> with handlers and state
const Img = handleHover(({
  handleHover,
  handleLeave,
  highlight,
  src
}) => (
  <img
    onMouseEnter={handleHover}
    onMouseLeave={handleLeave}
    className={`${highlight}`}
    src={src}
  />
))

// Use `IMG` in your component, each will maintain it's own highlight state
<Img src="1.jpg" />
<Img src="2.jpg" />
```